# GRAKN: Can I load a schema or data from a GRAQL file via the Java API?

Tags: vaticle-typeql, vaticle-typedb

Is it possible to load/import a schema or data from a GRAQL file via the Java API, e.g. in an in-memory graph?

```
import ai.grakn.Grakn
import ai.grakn.GraknTxType

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val session = Grakn.session(Grakn.IN_MEMORY, "db")
    val tx = session.open(GraknTxType.WRITE)

    // load a schema / import data from a gql file

    tx.close()
    session.close()
}
```

There are examples on the web site for [creating a schema](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/java-library/core-api) via `tx.putEntityType` etc. or [parsing queries](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/java-library/graql-api) but is it also possible to simply import a gql file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, you can read the whole file into a string and then do the following:

```
String readInFile = readWholeFile(....);
tx.graql().parse(readInFile).execute();
```

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks. (calling `execute` on the parsed query will load the schema or data).